# Can't Import SimPy

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, simpy

First of all I searched my problem and didn't find any solution. I imported SimPy in my Python script as "import simpy" and I assured that SimPy installed on my system via pip but nevertheless it couldn't be imported. I also added the picture shows output of pip list and result of my try to run script.

```
import simpy

def car(env):
    while True:
        print('Start parking at %d' % env.now)
        parking_duration = 5
        yield env.timeout(parking_duration)

        print('Start driving at %d' % env.now)
        trip_duration = 2
        yield env.timeout(trip_duration)

def main():
    env = simpy.Environment()
    env.process(car(env))
    env.run(until=15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Terminal output:
[image: Terminal output]

Comment: Run `python3 -m pip list`. Does it still list simpy?

Comment: There is no simpy but sympy.

Comment: I replaced simpy with sympy in the code and I got has no attribute error, but this code exactly same with official tutorial.

Comment: Why does your traceback says about line 24, while your script have 19 lines?

Comment: Also there is comments in file but I didn't add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you installed it for but run py2?

Try: `python3 SimPy.py`

Comment: That is exactly what he is running, judging from the screenshot.

Comment: I installed it via pip and pip3 and tried to run with python and python3 but same problem is occurred.

Comment: @TolgaKarahan Can you try renaming your `SimPy.py` to something different? Just in case `SimPy.py` overshadows `simpy` module

Comment: Yes, I tried this too and changed the name to simpy-tutorial.py but nothing changed.

Comment: I fixed this. I installed the packages with sudo privileges and tried to run without it and that's the problem. When I provided sudo privileges it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rename your script to something else.  It shadows the simpy package.